# Adding some space between the x-axis and the bars, in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following data frame:

```
df = data.frame(x = c('a', 'b'),
                y = c(2,4))
```

and the corresponding graph:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x,y)) + 
  geom_col()
```

[image]

My scale is going from 1 to 5 so I don't want the 0 to appear on the y axis but want the y axis to start at 1. Yet I still want the blank space below the bars.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x,y)) + 
  geom_col() + 
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(1,4)) +
  scale_y_continuous(
    expand = expand_scale(add = c(0.2,0)))
```

[image]

As you see, the y axis indeed starts at 1, but now the space below the 1 is filled with the black bar, and is no longer blank. The other posts I consulted deal with cases when the y axis starts at 0 so expand_scale() did the job. Not in my case.

Any idea on how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Don't know it. Want to give more details?\

Comment: If you want to produce a custom graphic with specific labels, you can just re-label the axis. But keep in mind that not including `0` and presenting the result as a bar chart is [pure blasphemy](http://lsr.nellco.org/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1506&context=nyu_plltwp).

Comment: I am not sure why it is a "pure blasphem". In my research, participants indicate the extend to witch they agree with a statement, from 1 (I don't agree) to 5 (I agree). So there is really no 0 in my data.

Comment: Then your use falls to the 'custom plot' category. A bar chart would have your 1-5 on the `x` axis, and response counts on the `y`. As far as I understand, you want to display a single case, drawing no mark if the answer was 1, and a bar from 1 to the answer value otherwise?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the limits in `scale_y_continuous` to indicate what range you want to show. `NA` in the limits is 'use the default'. Now, normally that would take the away both bars because they are out-of-bounds (oob), but you could fix that by setting the `oob` argument of the scales to `squish`, which is a function found in the scales package.

```
library(scales)

ggplot(df, aes(x,y)) + 
  geom_col() +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(1, NA), oob = squish)
```

[image]

Comment: It worked, thanks. Can you explain why the bars disappear if I just set the limits argument? Why are they out of range? The values in the data above are 2 and 4, so why setting limits  = c(1, NA) take the bars away?

Comment: ggplot sees the bars as rectangles that have `ymin = 0` coordinates, so when the `limits = c(1, NA)` the `ymin` will be below the lower limit. Therefore, the default behaviour (which uses `scales::censor()`) will remove these rectangles because the coordinates are out of bounds.

Answer (score 2):

In ggplot you can use `position_nudge()` to cheekily move an entire geom by a fixed distance:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x,y)) + 
      geom_col(position = position_nudge(y=1)) + #move everything up one
      ylim(c(0,5)) #set the y axis limits
```

Comment: I already have position = position_dodge() in my code. How can I use position_nudge() on it?

Comment: Have you tried just swapping `position_dodge()` for `position_nudge()`? Depending on your data it might do what you want. Otherwise I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

If I well understand your problem, you have several levels of response and you want for each individual to represent it. Could you consider a representation with a y axis which is discret ?

It doesn't avoid your problem of 0 or 1 but in fact only level are importants. If there is nothing it is just because you don't have the answer so it is 0. I don't know if you agree with my proposition :

```
df = data.frame(x = c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'),
                y = factor(c(1, 2, 3, 4), levels = 1:4))


ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) + 
  geom_col() +
  scale_y_discrete(expand = expansion(add = 1.2))
```

Comment: Both approach did not work. In both the 0 appears on the y axis. As I specified in the main text, I need the y axis to start at 1

Answer (score 0):

Change `coord_cartesian()` to the following:

```
coord_cartesian(ylim=c(1,5), expand=F)
```

Here's the full call to `ggplot()` with the change:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x,y)) + 
  geom_col() + 
  coord_cartesian(ylim=c(1,5), expand=F) +
  scale_y_continuous(
    expand = expand_scale(add = c(0.2,0)))
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.